# No conecta base de datos despues de cambiar version php 7.4 a 5.6

Tags: codeigniter, php5

el proyecto con el que estoy trabajando es en **Codeigniter**, lo habia echado a andar ya con **PHP 7.4** pero ahora que me di cuenta que ocupo PHP **5.6** lo estoy intentando echar a andar con el. El problema es que cuando cambio el PHP a 5.6 este lanza un error:

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 346

Pero cuando lo vuelvo a cambiar a PHP 7.4 si se conecta a la base de datos. Creo pensar que el error debe de estar en la configuracion de PHP 5.6 mas que en la conexion a la base de datos pero ocupo algun consejo que es lo que puedo hacer. Esta es mi configuracion de mi archivo database.php :

```
<?php 
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;


$db['default'] = array (

'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost', //this will be same
'username' => 'root',  //replace with your username
'password' => '',       //replace with your password
'database' => 'derecho',   //replace with your database name which you want to use
'port' => "3306", 
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: @masterguru es un proyecto hecho en CI 2.1.3 ya de hace bastantitos años

Comment: Es donde se carga la base de datos, tengo entendido que es algo que codeigniter lo trae por defecto asi que no debe haber error. Ahi carga la base de datos apartir del archivo database.php y como me funciona en el php 7.4

Comment: Mira de quitar el simbolo `@` en la instrucción `return @mysqli_connect(` de la función `db_connect` del archivo `system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php` a ver si te arroja más información de error

Comment: Message: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client | es lo que me muestra, parece que ahi esta el problema, lo checo y digo si puedo arreglar eso.

Comment: Mira aqui si algo de lo que dicen te sirve para arreglarlo pues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026939/php-mysqli-connect-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client-caching-sha2-pa

Comment: Aqui tambien lo explican un poco mejor: https://proyectoa.com/solucion-al-error-hy000-2054-caching_sha2_password-al-conectar-a-base-de-datos-mysql-8/  (pero ojo con eso porque no se la version de tu base de datos y no se si explican como tirar atras el dia que quieras usar otra version de php más moderna)